# Can a 30 gallon water heater use a 25 amp breaker?

Tags: water, water-heater

I have a 240V, 25 amp breaker which is feeding a 30 gallon water heater.

Is that normal and expected?  Is it good enough?

I do not know the amp or watt rating of the water heater.

Comment: What does the water heater require?  It should mention in the installation instructions.  Most want 30 amps with 10 gauge wire.

Comment: Why are you questioning it? If it's tripping then the breaker may not be large enough, the element may be leaking to ground, or the tank may be wired wrong and energizing both elements. If it's not tripping and not heating it's not a breaker issue, breakers don't push power, they just react by blocking excessive current flow.

Comment: The installation instructions for the model number on the tank can be downloaded, the watts will be on the label. **What's happening that makes you question the  breaker size**?

Answer (score 6):

Depends on the wattage of the elements, not the size of the tank.

I have a 40 gallon which only calls for 25A (4500W elements, 18.75A continuous load, derates to 23.4A - too much for 20A but does not need 30A for proper derating.) Still needs 10Ga copper wire, since it's a breaker larger than 20A.

5500W elements require 30A breakers (22.9A, 28.6A after derating)

5000W elements also need 30A breakers (20.8A, 26A after derating)

The labeling and installation instructions for the heater should specify the required supply amperage. More isn't better.

Answer (score 1):

It is large enough for protection of most residential water heaters, but may be too large to provide adequate protection. Breakers are selected to stop excessive flow, they don't push power.

The determine proper protection the NEC first says near the beginning of the book (110.3) to install as the installation instructions which are part of the *Listing* (UL or other) instruct to.

Then the NEC in 422.13 says the overcurrrent device and branch circuit conductors for storage type water heaters smaller than 120 gallons shall be not less than 125% of the rating of the appliance.

So if the instructions don't give specific instructions then you need to look at the label, it will typically specify element watts. To get amps you will need to divide by your system voltage of 240v or maybe 208v, but not 220v. 220v just doesn't exist. Once you determine amps then you select the next larger standard size listed in 240.6 of 20, 25, 30, 40... amps.

But typically at 25A has a tolerance of at least 110% of rating, so would hold 5500w rated tanks without tripping. Not correct, but likely not related to your problem.

Comment: In real life often I have found inspectors often accept (or fail to notice) 30A breakers and #10 wire protecting any residential water heater. (This is what I have found, not installed.)

Comment: Also your label may list the watts for upper and lower elements separately. don't add those numbers, only one element operates at a time.